# Powershell session to connect to Azure cloud service instance on AzureRM subscription

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a cloud service, deployed on modern Azure RM subscription. When I try to connect to PowerShell Session using the below recommended PowerShell command, I keep getting 404 even though the deployment exists. Any suggestions to get this working?

```
Get-AzureWinRMUri -ServiceName 'Servicename' -Name 'Instance_IN_0'

WARNING: No deployment found in service: 'Servicename'.
```

Comment: What does `Get-AzureRmContext` return? are you connected? i.e. have you run `Connect-AzureRmAccount` first?

Comment: Yes, Get-AzureRmContext returns me the subscription  context where the above service is deployed as a cloud service. I always had this issue with these deployments but i solved them with ClassicCompute Rest API but the powershell session doesn't have any Rest API that i can use to create a session. Running Classic cloud services on RM subscription is not supported with Azure automation it seems.

Comment: Try the command to get it. `$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <VMname>
$vm.OSProfile.WindowsConfiguration.WinRM.listeners`